# Tuple group limitation

Tags: c#, sql, tuples

How can I control the loop of Tuple repetition?

Someone has given me a hint about an algorithm, which I have modified a little.

```
int LimCol = Convert.ToInt32(LimitColis);

result = oListTUP
         .GroupBy(x => x.Item1)
         .Select(g => new
         {
             Key = g.Key,
             Sum = g.Sum(x => x.Item2),
             Poids = g.Sum(x => x.Item3),
         })
         .Select(p => new
         {
             Key = p.Key,
             Items = Enumerable.Repeat(LimCol , p.Sum  / LimCol).Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(p.Sum  % LimCol, 1)),
             CalculPoids = p.Poids / (Enumerable.Repeat(LimCol, p.Sum / LimCol).Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(p.Sum % LimCol, 1))).Count()
         })
         .SelectMany(p => p.Items.Select(i => Tuple.Create(p.Key, i, p.CalculPoids)))
                        .ToList();

foreach (var oItem in result)
{
     Label1.Text += oItem.Item1 + "--" + oItem.Item2 + "--" + oItem.Item3 + "<br>";
}
```

the result with LimCol = 3
[image: ScreenShot]

As you can see, I colored the problem with red.

PS: I have created some Tuple for not using data from SQL

```
 var list = new List<Tuple<string, int, decimal>>
        {
            Tuple.Create("0452632", 12, 15.0m),
            Tuple.Create("essai 49", 1, 45.0m),
            Tuple.Create("essai 49", 1, 45.0m),
            Tuple.Create("essai 49", 2, 45.0m),
            Tuple.Create("essai 49", 1, 23.0m),


        };

        int TheLimCol = 3;

        var Theresult = list
            .GroupBy(x => x.Item1)
            .Select(g => new
            {
                Key = g.Key,
                Sum = g.Sum(x => x.Item2),
                Poids = g.Sum(x => x.Item3),
            })
            .Select(p => new
            {
                Key = p.Key,
                Items = Enumerable.Repeat(TheLimCol, p.Sum / TheLimCol).Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(p.Sum % TheLimCol, 1)),

                CalculPoids = p.Poids / (Enumerable.Repeat(TheLimCol, p.Sum / TheLimCol).Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(p.Sum % TheLimCol, 1))).Count()

            })
            .SelectMany(p => p.Items.Select(i => Tuple.Create(p.Key, i, p.CalculPoids)))
            .ToList();

        foreach (var oItem in Theresult)
        {
            Label1.Text += oItem.Item1 + "--" + oItem.Item2 + "--" + oItem.Item3 + "<br>";
        }
```

Actual output:

```
0452632--3--3,0
0452632--3--3,0
0452632--3--3,0
0452632--3--3,0
0452632--0--3,0
essai 49--3--79,0
essai 49--2--79,0
```

expected result:

```
0452632--3--3,75
0452632--3--3,75
0452632--3--3,75
0452632--3--3,75
essai 49--3--79,00
essai 49--2--79,00
```

Comment: What is your question? It is not clear at all.

Comment: The problem is probably in "Enumerable.Repeat(LimCol , p.Sum  / LimCol)" (rounding problem?) but you don't gave enough information. Where is the value of LimitColis? What is the value of the Item2 properties in oListTUP?

Comment: Thanks you for responding, i add tupel example now

Comment: If you are unhappy that your `Item3` is always zero, then you have asked the same question twice.  You should go back and improve your earlier question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your ".Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(p.Sum % TheLimCol, 1)". You're adding an element even if the remainder (p.Sum % TheLimCol) is equal to 0.

This should work:

```
        var result = list
            .GroupBy(x => x.Item1)
            .Select(g => new
            {
                Key = g.Key,
                Sum = g.Sum(x => x.Item2),
                Poids = g.Sum(x => x.Item3),
            })
            .Select(p => new
            {
                Key = p.Key,
                Items = Enumerable.Repeat(limCol, p.Sum / limCol).Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(p.Sum % limCol, p.Sum % limCol > 0 ? 1 : 0)),
                CalculPoids = p.Poids / Enumerable.Repeat(limCol, p.Sum / limCol).Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(p.Sum % limCol, 1)).Count()
            })
            .SelectMany(p => p.Items.Select(i => Tuple.Create(p.Key, i, p.CalculPoids)))
            .ToList();
```

In this specific case, I would recommend using the alternative syntax of Linq (or not using Linq at all):

```
        var query = from x in list
                    group x by x.Item1 into g
                    let sum = g.Sum(x => x.Item2)
                    let poids = g.Sum(x => x.Item3)
                    let remainder = sum % limCol
                    let items = Enumerable.Repeat(limCol, sum / limCol).Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(remainder, remainder > 0 ? 1 : 0))
                    select new
                    {
                        Key = g.Key,
                        Items = items,
                        CalculPoids = poids / items.Count()
                    };


        var result = query.SelectMany(p => p.Items.Select(i => Tuple.Create(p.Key, i, p.CalculPoids)));
```